# Submit inputs the meteor way

Tags: meteor

I'm learning meteor and need to add the values from various inputs (or multiple forms) into mongo DB. I can do this via jquery by collecting the values, making a new object and then inserting this into the DB, but this doesn't seem very metero? Is there a better way I can submit multiple forms or inputs without using much or any jquery?

Comment: It's fine to use jQuery to collect your form inputs values and generate a document that you insert in the database. However, if you want to dig into something more Meteorish, I suggest using the autoform package, it's pretty amazing : http://atmospherejs.com/aldeed/autoform

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I'll have a look at this tomorrow!!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it via meteor templates. This example will take a value from your input box and add it to a property called "Total".

Say you have an text input field with an id "amount" and a submit button with an id "addAmount". Example of updating the value:

```
Template.nameOfYourTemplate.events({
        'click #addAmount': function(e) { //the button being clicked
            e.preventDefault();
            var amount = parseInt($('#amount').val()); //the input holding the value
            NameOfYourCollection.update(this._id, {$inc: {total: amount}});
        }
});
```